# getting following type of exception during execution using java and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pom.xml

while running following code getting null pointer exception but cross checked locater it is ok,

tried several time but getting same response,

pom class for login created
pom class for home page created
test class for creating pet

#################################################################

signin class

```
package com.Medeventage.crm.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Crm_create_Patient_page {

/**
 * 
 * All WebElements are identified by @FindBy annotation
 * 
 */
/// html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]
WebDriver driver;
// @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"actionMenuSidebar\"]/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]")
// WebElement createpetientbutton;
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='first_name']")
WebElement firstname;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='middle_name_c']")
WebElement middlename;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='last_name']")
WebElement lastname;

@FindBy(name = "birth_date")
WebElement datebox;

@FindBy(name = "gender")
WebElement genderdropdown;

@FindBy(name = "race")
WebElement racedropdown;

@FindBy(name = "ethnicity")
WebElement ethnicitydropdown;

@FindBy(name = "phone_home")
WebElement homephone;

@FindBy(name = "phone_mobile")
WebElement mobile;

@FindBy(name = "eaddress")
WebElement email;

@FindBy(name = "primary_care_physician")
WebElement pcpdropdown;

@FindBy(name = "address1")
WebElement address1;

@FindBy(name = "address2")
WebElement address2;

@FindBy(name = "city")
WebElement city;

@FindBy(name = "state1")
WebElement statedropdown;

@FindBy(name = "postal_code")
WebElement postalcode;

@FindBy(name = "cp_email_c")
WebElement emailcheckbox;

@FindBy(name = "sms_c")
WebElement smscheckbox;

@FindBy(css = "#EditView > div.buttons > input[type=button]:nth-child(1)")
WebElement save;

public Crm_create_Patient_page(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;

    // This initElements method will create all WebElements

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}

// //select create patient button
// public void clickcreatepatient() {
// Actions A = new Actions(driver);
// A.click(createpetientbutton).build().perform();

// }
// Set first name in textbox

public void setfName(String fName) {

    firstname.sendKeys(fName);
}
// Set middle name in textbox

public void setmiddleName(String mName) {

    middlename.sendKeys(mName);
}
// Set last name in textbox

public void setlastName(String lName) {

    lastname.sendKeys(lName);
}

public void setdate(String date) {

    datebox.sendKeys(date);
}

// select gender drop down
public void genderDropDown() {
    Select drop = new Select(genderdropdown);
    drop.selectByVisibleText("Male");
}

// select race drop down
public void raceDropDown() {
    Select drop = new Select(racedropdown);
    drop.selectByVisibleText("Declined to specify");
}

// select ethinicity drop down
public void ethinictyDropDown() {
    Select drop = new Select(ethnicitydropdown);
    drop.selectByVisibleText("Other");
}

public void sethomep(String hphone) {

    homephone.sendKeys(hphone);

}

public void setmphone(String mphone) {

    mobile.sendKeys(mphone);
}

public void setemailadd(String mail) {

    email.sendKeys(mail);

}

// select pcp drop down
public void pcpDropDown() {
    Select drop = new Select(pcpdropdown);
    drop.selectByVisibleText("Derick Trisha");

}
// Set address1 in textbox

public void setaddress1(String add1) {

    address1.sendKeys(add1);
}
// Set address2 in textbox

public void setaddress2(String add2) {

    address2.sendKeys(add2);
}
// Set city in textbox

public void setcity(String cit) {

    city.sendKeys(cit);
}

// select state drop down
public void stateDropDown() {
    Select drop = new Select(statedropdown);
    drop.selectByVisibleText("New York");

}
// Set postalcode in textbox

public void setpincode(String pincode) {

    postalcode.sendKeys(pincode);
}
// Select checkbox

public void clickmailbox() {
    boolean select = emailcheckbox.isSelected();
    System.out.print(select);
    // performing click operation if element is not already selected
    if (select == false) {
        emailcheckbox.click();
    }
}
// Select checkbox

public void clicksmsbox() {
    boolean select = smscheckbox.isSelected();
    System.out.print(select);
    // performing click operation if element is not already selected
    if (select == false) {
        smscheckbox.click();
    }
}

// click login button

public void clicksave() {
        save.click();
    }
}
```

Create Patient Class

```
package com.Medeventage.crm.test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.Medeventage.crm.pages.CrmLogin;
import com.Medeventage.crm.pages.Crm_create_Patient_page;
import com.Medeventage.crm.pages.Crmhomepage;

public class Crm_Create_Patient {
    public class Crm_login_valid_credential {

    String driverPath = "D:\\CHROME\\chromedriver.exe";

    WebDriver driver;

    CrmLogin objLogin;

    Crmhomepage objHomePage;
    Crm_create_Patient_page objcreatepage;

    @BeforeTest

    public void setup() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://uatcrm.medevantage.com/index.php?module=Users&action=Login");
        // creating object of loginpage

        objLogin = new CrmLogin(driver);

        // Verify login page title

        System.out.println("Log In Page Contains MDCRM As A Part Of title");
        String loginPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPageTitle.toLowerCase().contains("mdcrm"));
        System.out.println(loginPageTitle);
        // login to application

        objLogin.loginTocrm("admin", "admin");
        // go the next page
        objHomePage = new Crmhomepage(driver);
        // Verify home page
        String actualUrl = "https://uatcrm.medevantage.com/index.php?module=patie_patients&action=index";
        String expectedUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedUrl, actualUrl);
        System.out.println("Home Page Opened");
    }

    /**
     * 
     * This test go to
     * https://uatcrm.medevantage.com/index.php?module=Users&action=Login
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * Login to application
     * 
     * Verify the home page using Dashboard message
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * 
     */

    @Test(priority = 0)

    public void test_Home_Page_Appear_Correct() throws InterruptedException {

        // Adding Page Load Time out
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // clicking on create Patient page
        System.out.println("Clicking On Create Patient Tab");
        WebElement Createpetient = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]"));
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.click(Createpetient).build().perform();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        objcreatepage.setfName("Automate");
        objcreatepage.setmiddleName("demo");
        objcreatepage.setlastName("TestPatient");
        objcreatepage.setdate("05092021");
        objcreatepage.genderDropDown();
        objcreatepage.raceDropDown();
        objcreatepage.ethinictyDropDown();
        objcreatepage.sethomep("8989789678");
        objcreatepage.setmphone("8669164533");
        objcreatepage.setemailadd("autodemop@malinator.com");
        objcreatepage.setaddress1("Q11");
        objcreatepage.setaddress2("Church Road");
        objcreatepage.setcity("New York");

        // objcreatepage.createp("auto", "demo", "testpetient");

        // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // objcreatepage.creatp1("05092021", "8888888888", "8669164533",
        // "autodemo@malinator.com");
        // objcreatepage.creatp2("midletown", "Q101", "Church Road", "89767");
        String createpagetitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(createpagetitle);

     }
   }

}
```

Login Class

```
package com.Medeventage.crm.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class CrmLogin {

/**
 * 
 * All WebElements are identified by @FindBy annotation
 * 
 */

WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(name = "user_name")

WebElement userName;

@FindBy(name = "username_password")

WebElement password;

@FindBy(name = "Login")

WebElement login;

public CrmLogin(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;

    // This initElements method will create all WebElements

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}
// Set user name in textbox

public void setUserName(String strUserName) {

    userName.sendKeys(strUserName);
}

// Set password in password textbox

public void setPassword(String strPassword) {

    password.sendKeys(strPassword);

}

// Click on login button

public void clickLogin() {

    login.click();

}

/**
 * 
 * This POM method will be exposed in test case to login in the application
 * 
 * @param strUserName
 * 
 * @param strPasword
 * 
 * @return
 * 
 */

public void loginTocrm(String strUserName, String strPasword) {

    // Fill user name

    this.setUserName(strUserName);

    // Fill password

    this.setPassword(strPasword);

    // Click Login button

    this.clickLogin();

  }

}
```

Error :

##############################################################

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 33685
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1619767644.909][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 90.
Apr 30, 2021 12:57:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Log In Page Contains MDCRM As A Part Of title
MDCRM
Home Page Opened
Clicking On Create Patient Tab
FAILED: test_Home_Page_Appear_Correct
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Medeventage.crm.test.Crm_Create_Patient$Crm_login_valid_credential.test_Home_Page_Appear_Correct(Crm_Create_Patient.java:92)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Reporter [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0] failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:496)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:780)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.setParameters(XmlClass.java:233)
    at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlClasses(FailedReporter.java:199)
    at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.createXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:150)
    at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateXmlTest(FailedReporter.java:124)
    at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateFailureSuite(FailedReporter.java:64)
    at org.testng.reporters.FailedReporter.generateReport(FailedReporter.java:49)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1042)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting NPE on this line `objcreatepage.setfName("Automate");` for the object `objcreatepage`. I don't see any initialization of that object in your code. You have just declared it but haven't initialized it.

Can you confirm that's the line 92 in your class? I can't see the line numbers so don't know.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install TestNG. For me the testNG download link displays 404 error